# Export data from table to excel column name

Tags: sql-server-2005, export-to-excel

How can I export data from table to excel with column name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, you can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to export data to Excel.  Here's an article that might get you started:

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid87_gci1306800,00.html

On 2000, you can use Data Transformation Services (DTS).  Using DTS to export data to Excel was much easier than doing it in SSIS, it's too bad they made it more complicated in SSIS.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319951

There is also a simpler way to do it using OPENROWSET (this may require creating the Excel file before doing the export):

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202

One additional simple way to do this is to just query your database by dumping the values into a comma-separated list, then saving off the results as a .csv file.

The simpler methods might require some clever coding to get the column names into the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I found that first article _really_ useful. It's a cliche, but I'd vote your answer up twice if I could....

Comment: See my another same answer and it's discussion for same , you have not properly understand this.

Comment: I want it from sql script only.

Answer (score 3):

See: 
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1107
Copying column headers with grid query results in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio
Open SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and run your query.  Select Query | Query Options.  Select the Results / Grid setting and check "Include column headers when copying or saving the results".  Now when you copy the results in the results pane and paste them in excel you will get the coluumn names.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. In SSMS, Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results To Grid > Include Column Headers when Copying or Saving the Results.  You can then manually copy and save the grid results.
2. Use Microsoft Query from within Excel.
3. Right-click on the database, select Tasks > Export Data.  Use the Import/Export wizard.
4. Use SSIS
5. Programatically extract the values.

There are probably more, but that's a pretty good selection!